# Biasing using output charesteristics of a transistor

Tags: voltage, current, bias, base, collector

So this is output charesteristics of a transistor (ktc 3198)with variying base current values. Is it okay to design a voltage divider bias with output charesteristics as reference?

[image: output charesteristics]

Comment: You should add your intended circuit so we don't have to guess what you have in mind. In any case those curves are nominal and can vary widely for any individual transistor so you should not rely on them.

Comment: That I-V curve looks a lot more like a vacuum tube triode to me. (Just the curve shapes, not the units or magnitudes.) Here's what [the Early Effect looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDLGU.png) given that curve above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output characteristics of a transistor, like the one you've shown for the KTC 3198 in common emitter configuration, depict the relationship between the collector current (Ic) and the collector-emitter voltage (Vce) for different values of base current (Ib).

The voltage divider bias, (also known as the self-bias) is a method used to establish the Q-point (or operating point) of a transistor in the active region. This ensures that the transistor operates as an amplifier. To design a voltage divider bias circuit, one typically uses the transistor's input characteristics (which relates base current to base-emitter voltage) and the DC load line, which is derived from the circuit's resistor values.

However, the output characteristics can still provide useful information for designing a voltage divider bias. You can select a suitable Q-point from the output characteristics that ensures the transistor remains in the active region for the entire input signal, preventing clipping.

The operating point should ideally be in a region where the output characteristic curves are reasonably spaced and linear. This ensures the transistor amplifies the signal without significant distortion.

The output characteristics can help you understand the limits of Vce where the transistor may go into saturation (fully on) or cutoff (fully off).

However, solely relying on the output characteristics is not sufficient. The input characteristics and the DC load line play a crucial role in determining the base resistors for the voltage divider biasing scheme.

In conclusion, while the output characteristics can provide valuable information, it's important to refer to the transistor's input characteristics and the circuit parameters to design an effective voltage divider bias. Hope this helps.